# From float to string without losing zeros (conda/python/jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, format

I am doing data analysis with jupyter notebook using python and pandas. In my master csv, thousands are indicated with dots and python reads the columns as a float. I want to eliminate the dots and do some calculations afterwards.
If I transform the column into a string, I lose the zeros from the thousands.

```
df['name_of_a_new_column'] = df['Name_of_The_column_it_is_a_float'].astype(str)
```

The result is from 249.000 to 249.0

Is there any way to change from float to interger or string without losing zeros from thousands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> In my master csv, thousands are indicated with dots

Read the original CSV with the `thousands` option:

data.csv:

```
column1,column2
1.000.000,2.000.000
```

test.py:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',thousands='.')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   column1  column2
0  1000000  2000000
```

See the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation for lots of other options to control reading the CSV.  For example some countries use comma for decimal point in floats (`decimal=','`), and semicolon for column separators (`sep=';'`) in their CSVs as well.